# Is there a way to ensure that Python interpreter always finds a module?

Tags: python, module

So, I have no clue why my Python interpreter is struggling to find some modules. I'm trying to use mysql.connector after installing with

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

I use sys.path to find where exactly my interpreter is looking for the modules. mysql.connector 100% IS in one of the paths that the interpreter looks for. When I start to type ...

```
import
```

... VSCode's autocomplete even finds mysql, so it is being picked up. BUT, when I run the code with 'import mysql.connector':

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
```

I swear this was working fine yesterday too. Please help. In addition, could someone explain how to prevent this from happening in the future, in general?
I get the same problem when trying to use watchdog.observers. VSCode autocomplete so I know it is picking up the module somewhere, but the interpreter can't find it!

Comment: Once verify that you have correct interpreter set for your project. Vs has option set change the interpreter. If you have venv make sure your interpreter points to venev python.exe file

Comment: How to I do that?

Comment: Try this --https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/selecting-a-python-environment-for-a-project?view=vs-2019